# Clipboard management like Linux in Windows

Tags: windows-7, linux, clipboard, selection

In Linux, if I select a text I can paste it in another place with a click of middle mouse button and there is no need to right click and copy or using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> hotkeys for doing so.

Also the selected text does not interfere with the normal copy paste actions.
Is there anyway I can emulate the same in Windows 7?

Answer (score 0):

For Windows XP, Microsoft released a powertoy called TweakUI; it includes a feature called X-Mouse, which would do what you need, but I don't know if it works with Windows 7.