# Is there a Linux style clipboard available for Windows?

Tags: linux, windows, clipboard

I like being able to highlight text and paste it with the middle mouse button while still having the actual clipboard available through cntrl+c and cntrl+v.  This way I can have 2 pieces of text copied at the same time.

I'm looking for a way to mimic this behavior in Windows because I do not have a Linux system at work.

Comment: You can copy and paste into a command console by using "edit" and right clicking copy or paste.  The next version of Windows, Windows 10, will have an updated command console that supports the shortcuts without going into edit mode.  There are hundreds of tools that replace the command prompt I would use one of those if you can't wait.

Comment: @Ramhound, this isn't for the command prompt.  On my Linux machine I can highlight text from anywhere, and use the middle mouse button to paste it, but I can use the clipboard separately from that method so I effectively have 2 clipboards.  This works across all my applications and I would like that functionality in Windows.

Comment: So you want to be able to copy and paste with your mouse on Windows?  There are dozens of clipboard tools that exist, one might extend that feature,  depending on the version of Windows your using [this](http://superuser.com/questions/308485/clipboard-management-like-linux-in-windows?rq=1) might apply.

Comment: @Ramhound, Well, it isn't exactly copy and paste because it's a different clipboard.  I like it because It's simple to use and I can have 2 blobs of text copied at once.  I didn't think to look at other clipboard managers for that specific feature but I guess that just makes too much sense!  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Windows only has one clipboard.  Since this feature does not exist out of the box, you will have to turn to a third-party application, to extend the clipboard to work like you want.  The application might exist or you might have to create it yourself.  The linked question proves it can be done, the linked answer, just does not apply to more recent versions of Windows though.

Comment: @Ramhound, Yeah I noticed that.  It's odd that this feature isn't more readily available.  I will have to look into creating my own.  I have looked into clipboard managers and they just don't do what I need.  I am a programmer, and I need to be able to copy and paste multiple selections quickly without saving them to a manager and assigning hotkeys.  But once again, I appreciate your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clipboard management like Linux in Windows](http://superuser.com/questions/308485/clipboard-management-like-linux-in-windows).